# Using set operators with python regex module

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm having trouble getting set operators to work in the regex module (regex 2013-11-29) in python-3.x. For example, to match ASCII characters minus punctuation I have tried:

```
import regex as rx

data = '(foo)'
for m in rx.finditer(r'[\p{ASCII}--\p{P}]+',data):
    print(m.group(0))     # expect 'foo', getting '(foo)'
```

The documentation gives this example:

[\p{N}--[0-9]] # Set containing all numbers except '0' .. '9'

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to explicitly opt into Version 1 behavior so that the -- is interpreted as a set operator and not as characters to include in the class.

From the [module web page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

> Version 1 behaviour (new behaviour, different from the current re
>   module):
>
> Indicated by the VERSION1 or V1 flag, or (?V1) in the pattern.
>
> .split will split a string at a zero-width match.
>
> Inline flags apply to the end of the group or pattern, and they can be
>   turned off.
>
> Nested sets and set operations are supported.
>
> Case-insensitive matches in Unicode use full case-folding by default.
>
> If no version is specified, the regex module will default to
>   regex.DEFAULT_VERSION. In the short term this will be VERSION0, but in
>   the longer term it will be VERSION1.